I can't use MEMBER OF or IN (SubSelect) in a package with variables
I want to use this code in a package:
Declare
    TYPE mc01TableTYPE IS TABLE OF Varchar2(4);
    v_MC01Table     mc01TableTYPE := mc01TableTYPE();
    v_ResTable      mc01TableTYPE := mc01TableTYPE();
    TYPE string_list IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);
    Var_All         string_list := string_list('var1', 'var2');
BEGIN
-- Fill the collecteion for the test
    v_MC01Table.Delete;
    Select MC01
    Bulk Collect Into v_MC01Table
    From My_Table
    Where PDATE=SysDate
    Order by MC01;

--  This makes the errors
    Select MC01
    Bulk Collect Into v_ResTable
    From My_Table
    Where PDATE Between Sysdate-1 And SysDate
    And MC01 MEMBER OF Var_All;
    --And MC01 IN (SELECT MC01 FROM TABLE(Var_All));

-- Only for watch the result
    For i in 1..v_ResTable.Count
    Loop
        Dbms_Output.Put_Line('v_ResTable('||i||'): '||v_ResTable(i));
    End Loop;
End;

The MEMBER OF command gives these errors:
PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed
PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected UDT got CHAR
If I change the MEMBER OF line to this.
And MC01 IN (SELECT MC01 FROM TABLE(Var_All));

then I get these errors:
PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed
PL/SQL: ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item
I have a working solution with the LIKE operator, but I want to know how to use the nested table in this case.

You would need a schema-level collection type, not a PL/SQL collection type - see this answer for an example. Are you able to create your own types?

Even if the IN query worked (it doesn't as you cannot use locally defined PL/SQL collections) it then fail for a subsequent error as the collection does not have a MC01 column. Instead, you want And MC01 IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(Var_All)); (but that is mostly academic as you can't use a locally defined collection). As @AlexPoole says, define your collection type in the SQL scope (as I did in your previous question) rather than in the local PL/SQL scope and both MEMBER OF and IN (with COLUMN_VALUE) should work.

Alternatively, if you cannot create a user-defined type in the SQL scope you could use one of the built-in collections such as: Var_All  SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST := SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('var1', 'var2'); and then use And MC01 IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(Var_All)); (unfortunately, the SYS.ODCI*LIST types are VARRAYs and not nested table types so they support the TABLE collection expression but not the MEMBER OF operator so you have to use IN).

Thanks MTO again! It works in a noname block. I hope that I can successfully implement it in my package as well!
And as Alex commented: How can I create my own type in a package?

@zotta - which approach did you use? If you created a schema-level type then that will just work in the package in the same way; but you can't replace that with a PL/SQL type defined in your package if that's what you're asking, as that will get the same errors. If you used the SYS varray types then that should also just work.

@Alex - I used the SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST. But I would like to know how can I create my own schema-level collection type, which I can use in my package.

@Zolta - with create type (docs), which MT0 showed on yur previous question, and it's also shown in the duplicate questions.

Thanks guys for your help and understanding :) Now I've learned how to create a schema level type! I use this solution with the MEMBER clause. How do I add the "thank you" check mark now?
